# Javascript Promise. Как прервать длинную цепочку then?

Tags: javascript, promise

Если цепочка промисов:

```
Promise(function(resolve, reject) {...}))
.then(function() {return [Новый проимс]})
.then(function() {return [Новый проимс]})
.then(function() {return [Новый проимс]})
и т.д.
```

Нужно иметь возможность прервать ее и, например, запустить функцию, создающую промис, снова, либо любую дургую, предшествующую ей, не суть.
reject пока не использую, при ошибке делаю resolve(0). Да и reject не решает проблему:

```
Promise(function(resolve, reject) {reject();}))
.then(function() {return [Новый проимс]},
function() {[Ошибка]}) // Здесь можно обработать ошибку
.then(function() {return [Новый проимс]}) // Код продолжит выполнение в любом случае
```

Пока вижу только такой выход: при ошибке делать resolve(0) и на каждом этапе делать проверку, проталкивая ошибку до конца:

```
.then(function(rez) {
if(!rez) {[Запуск Функции При Ошибке]; return rez;} else {return [Новый проимс]}
})
.then(function(rez) {
if(!rez) {[Запуск Функции При Ошибке]; return rez;} else {return [Новый проимс]}
})
```

Но это лишний код. Как сделать так, чтобы следующий .then просто не сработал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зря вы не используете `reject` - он делает именно то, что вам нужно.

А чтобы обработать ошибку - но оставить ее ошибкой - надо использовать `return Promise.reject(...)` или `throw ...` в обработчике ошибки:

```
new Promise(function(_, reject) { reject(); })
  .then(function() { console("ok") }, function() { console.log("rejected"); return Promise.reject(); })
  .then(function() { console("ok") })
  .then(function() { console("ok") }, function() { console.log("rejected"); return Promise.reject(); })

// вывод:
// rejected
// rejected
```